# StringBuffer does not read completely

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

I have a simple function for connecting to a server and returning the response as a string. It works fine when the size of data returned is small but when the response is large. It does not store the returned response string by the server completely and ends the string with ... 
Surprisingly the system.out.println returns the correct response. Please help me out. I am really stuck.

```
protected String getResponseFromServer(String URLaddress) {

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    URL serverAddress = null;
    BufferedReader rd = null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        serverAddress = new URL(URLaddress);
        // set up out communications stuff
        connection = null;
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) serverAddress.openConnection();
        connection.setReadTimeout(20000);
        connection.connect();
        // read the result from the server
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.print(line.trim());
            sb.append(line.trim());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // close the connection, set all objects to null
        connection.disconnect();
        connection = null;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: How are you printing the result? It could just be your logging framework truncating the output. To be really sure, verify by checking the length of the returned string.

Comment: What happened to the `sb.append(line.trim(), 0, line.length());` you had originally (and on which I based my answer)?

Comment: Would you mind showing how you print it? You're generating too much curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting that truncated string (ends with ...) while you debug? Try System.out.println(sb.toString()); before you return.

Comment: Yeah it shows the complete text with System.out.println... Dat was a very silly mistake. But the data I was receiving was JSON string which was was converting to JSONObject and it was throwing exception as invalid JSON... Thank You.. But now also it creates the same problem sometimes..

Answer (score 2):

*(edit: This answer is based on the code that OP has posted originally. The question has since been edited by the OP to change the offending code.)*

One bug is here:

```
sb.append(line.trim(), 0, line.length());
```

If `line` has any leading or trailing whitespaces, `line.length()` will be greater than `line.trim().length()`. In this case [`sb.append()` would throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int%29):

> `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if `start` or `end` are negative, or `start` is greater than `end` or **`end` is greater than `s.length()`**

Comment: As far as I can see, the OP is just calling `sb.append(line.trim())`. Where did you spot this version?

Comment: @adarshr: By the look of things this line of code got edited out of the question after I posted the answer. Let me ask the OP...